# Finding and removing unused tables in database (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone have an approach for finding and removing unused tables in a databases? I am using PHPMyAdmin. Removing the table is straightforward enough. I am unable to list tables by data of last use, or last accessed, or anything of that nature.

An example would be as following: 
Install a WordPress plugin. Uninstalling the plugin and then the table is left in the database. Does anyone have a proper technique for finding tables not in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a feature for this to determine when the table was last updated.

```
 SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname';
```

> Beginning with MySQL 5.7.2, UPDATE_TIME displays a timestamp value for
>   the last UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE performed

[MySQL table information schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html)

To determine inactive tables, you may have a check on this table based on UPDATE_TIME, as below

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
   AND UPDATE_TIME <= 'date 'X' months back';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think update time isn't a great means of determining whether a table's actually in use as there could be plugins that don't update the table on every access.

Comment: My apologies for the delay. This seems to be a proper answer. I need to pose the question differently I suppose.

Comment: @SrikanthA: what if I have MySQL version lower then < 5.7.2?